# How do I add an enum using protobuf-net in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, enums, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I'm trying to create an enumeration that follows this structure:

```
Enum Foo
 Bar=0
 One=1
End Enum
```

I read the documentation at https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/wiki/Attributes but I'm still unclear on how to add enumerations. I've tried adding `<ProtoEnum(#)>` and `<ProtoMember(#)>` above my enumeration but I'm getting the error "Attribute cannot be applied because the attribute is not valid on this declaration type".

What is the correct syntax for adding an enumeration to the Proto file in VB.NET using protobuf-net?

Answer (score 0):

I always feel dumb after seeing how simple syntax problems are:

```
<ProtoContract()>
Public Enum Foo

'<ProtoMember(0)> I don't think <ProtoMember> is required inside an enum
Bar = 0

'<ProtoMember(1)>
One = 1

End Enum
```